# Euler's method for exact solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, numerical-methods

We know that the solution of

$$y'=y$$

with $y(0)=1$
is

$$y=e^{x}$$

As far as I see the Euler's method is explicitly used only to find the numerical approximation of e.g. $y(3)$. Can we use the Euler's method to solve this differential equation and find the exact solution?

Edit:

I thought of the following:
$$y(t_1+\delta t) = y(t_0) + y'(t_1) \delta t$$
$$y(t_1+2\delta t) = y(t_1+\delta t) + y'(t_1+\delta t) \delta t$$
$$...$$
and from that we could find a recursive solution for $y(t_0)$. Then by taking the limit $\lim_{\delta t \to 0}$ of it, it could be possible to find the general solution of $y$ for every $t_0$ in the domain.

Is it impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the process you're envisioning, if you did it rigorously, becomes equivalent to Picard's iterative process: Given an initial value problem $y'(t)= f(t,y)$, $y(0) = y_0$, the sequence of functions defined by
\begin{align*}
    \phi_0(t) &= y_0 \\
    \phi_{k+1}(t) &= y_0 + \int_0^t f(s,\phi_k(s))\,ds
\end{align*}
converges to a solution $\phi(t)$.

(You can think of that integral as summing $f(s,\phi_k(s))$ at many discrete points between $s=0$ and $s=t$, multiplied by a small amount $\Delta s$, and taking the limit as $\Delta s \to 0$.)

In your problem, you have $f(t,y) = y$ and $y_0 = 1$.  Picard's process gives:
\begin{align*}
    \phi_0(t) &= 1 \\
    \phi_1(t) &= 1 + \int_0^t \phi_0(s)\,ds = 1 + \int_0^t 1\,ds = 1 + t \\
    \phi_2(t) &= 1 + \int_0^t(1+s)\,ds = 1 + t + \tfrac{1}{2}t^2 \\
    \phi_3(t) &= 1 + \int_0^t\left(1 + s + \tfrac{1}{2}s^2\right)\,ds = 1 + t + \tfrac{1}{2}t^2 + \tfrac{1}{6} t^3
\end{align*}
You can see that $\phi_k(t)$ is the $k$-th degree Taylor polynomial for $\phi(t) = e^t$, and that is the solution to the IVP.

Comment: Yes! That's what I basically did but in a very simple and primitive way! The problem with my way is that someone could argue that it doesn't follow mathematical rules and it's just an intuitive explanation of how this differential equation could be solved! But I was told that in mathematics you must follow rules rather than following your intuition! That's something that I cannot accept but right now I have no other chance but to follow those rules, even if I don't understand them!

Comment: @AnastassisKapetanakis Intuition is very important in math, but so are the rules.  Without the rules, you can reach paradoxes, and you could accidentally reject counterintuitive truths.  But take heart; you had a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

No.  Euler's method is only an approximation.  To determine the exact value of $y$ at time $t+\delta t$ (regardless of whether the ODE has an exact solution), you would need to keep all terms of the Taylor expansion for the solution.  Euler's method gives
$$y(t+\delta t) \approx y(t) + y'(t) \delta t,$$
whereas the exact solution at $t+\delta t$ is
$$y(t+\delta t) = y(t) + y'(t) \delta t + \frac{1}{2}y''(t)\delta t^2 + \cdots.$$

In particular, Euler's method will only be exact if the solution is affine (of the form $y = ax+b$) so that all derivatives beyond the first derivative are zero.

Comment: I added something more in the question. Could you please read that and say to me where I am wrong?

Comment: Hmm.  I don't have time right now to study your method in detail, but the point is that the source of error is due to the step size $\delta t$.  So, even something very simple like Euler's method becomes exact if we take the limit as $\delta t$ goes to zero.  You might experiment with your approach and see if your approximation works better than Euler's method.  Hope this helps.

Comment: If I find time tomorrow I am going to make a simple explanation of my "pseudo-method". I tried it in that simple differential equation and by some manipulations I managed to end up with this exact solution. My problem is that I searched a lot around google to find such a way of solving differential equations but I didn't find anything!